# Animating a mesh deformation using python

Tags: python, animation, keyframes

I have a 3D mesh in Blender that undergoes some modifications. The mesh is imported from python data. By using a python script, I modify the location of the vertices of the mesh to move them along the normal according to a function which is defined for every single vertex in the mesh. This function is also defined for `N` frames and determines the amount of vertex translation along the local normal for each frame, i.e. `f(iVertex, iFrame)`. This can create an animation if played from frame number `1` to frame `N`. In addition, the mesh itself is not translating or rotating and in fact, it is its shape that undergoes gradual deformation and change. I am looking for a strategy that can animate this shape deformation using a python script.

Comment: Since you have the function just append it to a handler ( frame_change_pre )  you'll have to wrap it in another function to loop through verts

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestion. It worked just fine.

Comment: you should write an answer to help others with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [Chebhou](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/5113/chebhou), the problem can be addressed perfectly and very elegantly by using [`frame_change_pre`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_61_0/bpy.app.handlers.html). I was inspired by the example that was posted [here](http://blenderscripting.blogspot.com/2012/09/python-driven-animaion.html) and I bring it here for the readers' convenience:

```
import bpy
import math

# for demo it creates a cube if it doesn't exist,
# but this can be any existing named object.
if not 'Cube' in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

frames_per_revolution = 120.0
step_size = 2*math.pi / frames_per_revolution


def set_object_location(n):
    x = math.sin(n) * 5
    y = math.cos(n) * 5
    z = 0.0
    ob = bpy.data.objects.get("Cube")
    ob.location = (x, y, z)

# every frame change, this function is called.
def my_handler(scene):
    frame = scene.frame_current
    n = frame % frames_per_revolution

    if n == 0:
        set_object_location(n)
    else:
        set_object_location(n*step_size)


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```